# What are offical requirements for Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: installation, 64-bit, performance, system-requirements

I have A Pentium Dual Core 2.50 Ghz and having  2GB DDR2 ram and 512 MB Nvidia 8 Series graphic card. Will Ubuntu 13.04 run on my system faster than Windows 7. Would I be able to run 64 Ubuntu on my PC?

Answer (score 0):

As your hardware specification you can easily install the Ubuntu. And about running faster than windows try yourself and you find the performance . You can install 64 bit ubuntu 12.04 LTS or latest release of ubuntu 13.04 .